# shortcut for event handling doing off+on+return false

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I find myself doing a lot of:

```
jelem.off('click').on('click', e => { somefunc(e); return false; } );
```

or

```
jelem.off('submit').on('submit', e => { somefunc(e); return false; } );
```

two things repeat here - the `off` before `on` and the `return false;`

Is there a way for me to extend jquery to add a shortcut such as 'myOn' so that:

```
jelem.myOn('click', e => somefunc(e));
```

will be equivalent to `jelem.off('click').on('click', e => { somefunc(e); return false; } );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ended up with:

```
(function( $ ) {
     $.fn.offOn = function(eventName, callback) {
        this.off(eventName).on(eventName, callback);
    };
     $.fn.offOnX = function(eventName, callback) {
        this.off(eventName).on(eventName, e => { callback(e); return false; });
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

Answer (score 1):

You may create your own jquery plugin. I hope this would help to your problem.

> $.fn.myOn = function(e, option){  //code here };

Reference: https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/